# ValueError: Missing scheme in request url: h in python

Tags: python, xpath, error-handling, web-scraping, web-crawler

This is my code and i am trying to access a review from this site but showing an error.

```
class DomainCrawlSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "Spider"
    allowed_domains = ["www.smahavarkar.wordpress.com"]
    start_urls = "http://smahavarkar.wordpress.com/"

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        titles = hxs.select("//p")
        items = []
        for titles in titles:
            item = DItem()
            item ["address"] = titles.select("a/text()").extract()
            item ["review1"] = titles.select("p/text()").extract()
            item.append(item)
        return item
```

Comment: ValueError: Missing scheme in request url: h

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`start_urls` should be a list, try changing to:

```
start_urls = ["https://www.zomato.com/cs/mumbai/restaurace?q=pop%20tates"]
```

Comment: what is the full traceback?

Comment: though I'm pretty sure your problem is that it should be `items.append(item)`.

Comment: SOrry for mistake but How do i fix it it seems all code is correct

Comment: `item.append(item)` becomes `items.append(item)`

Answer (score 0):

Change `start_urls` to:

```
start_urls = ("http://smahavarkar.wordpress.com/",)
```

It worked for me.